# Error al grabar, query

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

Aquí tengo mi consulta

```
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result
```

Acá tengo la función que lee la tabla, toma la fecha de estudiante la resto a la fecha actual y de esa resta, quiero actualizar en la tabla el campo (Dias), esto quiero hacerlo con cada uno de los registros de la tabla. Aquí la función.

```
def actualizar_estudiantes(self):
     miFecha=StringVar()
     miID1=StringVar()
     Fec_Act=datetime.datetime.today()
     query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela' 
     db_rows = self.run_query(query) 
     for database_escuela in db_rows:
         wdias=0
         miID1.set(database_escuela[0])
         miID = miID1.get()
         miFecha.set(database_escuela[6])
         Fec_Est = miFecha.get()
         Fec_est1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(Fec_Est), '%d/%m/%Y')
         wdias=((Fec_Act - Fec_est1).days)
         query = 'UPDATE escuela SET DIAS1 = ? WHERE ID = ?'
         parameters = (wdias, miID)
     self.run_query(query, parameters)
```

Mi problema ahora es que solo graba el ultimo registro y  cuando coloco el  - self.run_query(query, parameters) dentro de for se bloquea la base de datos, me genera error, si me pueden dar alguna orientación, por favor.

Comment: Si traduces la query: ` 'UPDATE escuela SET DIAS1 = ? WHERE DIAS1 = ?'` -> `actualiza escuela asignando a dias1 el valor X dónde dias1 es Y`. Debes pasar la fecha original como segundo parámetro, le pasas la misma a los dos... No obstante esto modificaría todas las filas que coincidan con esa fecha, no solo la de ese estudiante... ¿tu tabla tiene alguna id que identifique de forma única a un estudiante?

Comment: Si la tabla tiene ID único que identifica cada estudiante

Comment: Hola,  actualice el código, solo que si coloco el  self.run_query(query, parameters), dentro de for se bloquea la base de datos y si lo dejo fuera solo actualiza el ultimo registro, que opción tengo o esta mal mi sintaxis de grabar.